# How to pass a function to a Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to insert a Meteor template (a simple login form) but I want to control what happens after the form is submitted. Ideally, I'd like to be able to pass a function `afterLogin()` to the template. But I'm quite unsure how to do this and if this is even possible.

I've recently seen an interesting package [`viewmodel`](http://viewmodel.meteor.com/) and I'm not sure how related it is. But the goal in this context is basically to render a view with a different view model.

Any ideas? I'm currently using a session variable and then after login, I check that session variable to run the correct function but this is ugly and not easy to work with. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I do it :

I assume that your login form is called from within a parent template, use the attributes syntax to pass the value of a custom helper to the data context of the login form.

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> loginForm options=loginFormOptions}}
</template>
```

The helper returns an object encapsulating a function, the caller is responsible for setting this function to whatever they want.

```
Template.parent.helpers({
  loginFormOptions:function(){
    return {
      afterLogin:function(){
        // we assert that the context is correct :
        // this will print Template.loginForm
        console.log(this.view.name);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Your login form code, acting as a library, can read from its data context the function that was passed by the caller template, and then call the function with the proper `this` context.

```
Template.loginForm.events({
  "submit":function(event,template){
    // ...
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(...,function(error){
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
      // guard against the existence of the custom afterLogin function
      if(template.data.options && template.data.options.afterLogin){
        // execute the custom function with proper context
        template.data.options.afterLogin.call(template);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thats it. I suppose you have to pass the function wrapped in an object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use **Iron Router** for navigating through different views of my application, you can get it here:
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router

```
meteor add iron:route
```

Then, check http://docs.meteor.com/#template_events. I would use something like:

```
Template.loginFormTemplate.events({
  'click .loginButton': function() {
    //... if success login ...
    Router.go('nextScreen');
  }
});
```

**[Update 1]**

I am afraid that trying to pass function to Route is an **ugly** approach in a sense of Meteor architecture.

You can try though, defining some Global variable, which is responsible for listening and forward-triggering events across the Routes

```
var eventHelper = (function () {
    var self = _.extend({
        afterLogin: function () {
            self.trigger('forwardedEvent');
        }}, Backbone.Events);

    return self;
})();


Route1.events({
    'click': function () {
        //... Let's call after login
        eventHelper.afterLogin();
    }
});

eventHelper.on('forwardedEvent',function() {
   // ... 
});
```

Comment: I am using iron router. The problem is that rather than `Router.go('nextScreen')`, I want to call an arbitrary function that is passed to the template...